# Is Anime series halal or haram?

Tags: halal-haram

As we heard and know that watching TV for example Hindu movies, America movies etc is Haram(forbidden), Only watching animals, things and world is halal. 
So we ask; can we watch Anime series (similar to cartoon)?

Comment: Where did you hear that watching Hindu movies or American movies is Haram?

Comment: @user921: Watching these movies Is haram, as they have music(haram), and all sorts of nudity, (or women without hijab) in them

Answer (score 5):

As a general rule, there mustn't be a problem as a Haram act if the Anime doesn't consist of Haram scene or other relevance Haram items.(if it is similar to cartoon without any bad scene).

Comment: what do you mean by bad scenes?

Comment: nice question, I mean bad scenes such as sexual scene or negative scenes who can has negative effect on the beliefs or lust or ... / Good luck dear mate

Answer (score 1):

Mostly Anime have uncovered girls, Music and lost of haram acts. As far as i know, there is no anime (or cartoons) in which female characters wears hijab and there is no Musical instruments being played). So as they have mostly Haram things, they should be avoided. But in case you can Always SKIP every haram part, then you can watch.

Comment: But how to skip every part haram?

Comment: that is almost impossible :) thats why its better not to watch them, or you can ask someone to first watch all of anime, before you watch them, and cut ALL haram scenes, with music and anything haram in it, and then show it to you